# Beautify ERB files in rails3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Is there a standalone tool or gem which can be used to beautify HTML  with ERB code(html.erb file). Is it better to do it through gem or through online beautifier? Needs guidance.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean beautify the html.erb file or the rendered HTML in the browser?

Comment: I mean to beautify the html.erb file

Comment: I dont want the rendered HTML in the browser is beautified

Comment: Got it. The only thing I'm aware of is this sublime plugin: https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby which uses https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [htmlbeautifier](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier) which has ERB support and is used by [BeautifyRuby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) package.

```
htmlbeautifier file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Sublime Text as your editor, there is a [Beautify Ruby Package](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) you can use.

Comment: And if you're on Github Atom, see the `atom-beautify` package which comes with (highly configurable) support for everything from HTML / CSS / JS to backend languages like Ruby, Rust, PHP, and Go.